# Displaying a message from inbox as a toast or alert

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I am getting the balance through a message and I want to display that message as an alert or toast. What I can do for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a site where you can get a large, ready to use piece of code. Can you please narrow the problem down a bit - where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

1) register an SMSBroadcastReceiver

2) parse out the message

3) start a new Activity, then launch a new AlertDialog from there

Again, like others I don't know how far you've really gone into this so I cannot suggest anything more in specific.